# How to get a list of global temporary tables in the current database?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, temporary-tables

I am trying to get a list of the global temporary tables that are currently active. There seems to be an issue with them bumping in to each other (same name). As the 'acting' dba, trying to sort out a mess here.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? (DB2, Oracle and Teradata all use them)

Comment: Sorry, SQL Server 2005.

Comment: They're bumping into each other because that's precisely what global temporary tables do - hence the name `global`. I have found very few practical uses for them myself.

Comment: I agree with @AaronBertrand on this topic.  There has to be a very strict and explicit requirement for global temp tables.

Comment: I am only trying to patch up an already patched up system.  Duct tape over bandaids.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For SQL Server 2005+, all global temp tables (tables that are created with a `##` prefix) will be found in tempdb.  This should work for you:

```
SELECT * FROM tempdb.sys.tables
WHERE name LIKE '##%'
```

Comment: See my comment on the question.